# How to find next match by ":help"?

Tags: help-system

For example, you are using "mattn/emmet.vim", and command `:help todo`, it shows emmet-todo. Not vim side's todo.

I'd like to find vim side's todo, but can't go to next match... how can I go to next match?

Comment: `:help todo<tab><tab><tab>`

Comment: Thank you , it solves.

Comment: In the help window do `:tselect /.*todo`